# How to delete ALL fields in Firestore document but keep the blank document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As the title shows, I'm searching a direct command to delete all the fields of a document without deleting the document itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `docRef.set({})`?

Comment: Yes, thank you! Very easy but I think there wasn't a question yet, maybe could be useful for someoneother.